# Why does gas cost explode with more than 7 variables in a struct

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, gas-price, gas-estimate

I'm assuming this has to do with Ethereum's 7 variable stack limit but in the following code test

```
  struct TestStruct5 {
    uint8 m_nOther1;
    uint8 m_nOther2;
    uint8 m_nOther3;
    uint8 m_nOther4;
    uint8 m_nOther5;
  }



struct TestStruct6 {
    uint8 m_nOther1;
    uint8 m_nOther2;
    uint8 m_nOther3;
    uint8 m_nOther4;
    uint8 m_nOther5;
    uint8 m_nOther6;
  }

  struct TestStruct7 {
    uint8 m_nOther1;
    uint8 m_nOther2;
    uint8 m_nOther3;
    uint8 m_nOther4;
    uint8 m_nOther5;
    uint8 m_nOther6;
    uint8 m_nOther7;
  }

  struct TestStruct8 {
    uint8 m_nOther1;
    uint8 m_nOther2;
    uint8 m_nOther3;
    uint8 m_nOther4;
    uint8 m_nOther5;
    uint8 m_nOther6;
    uint8 m_nOther7;
    uint8 m_nOther8;
  }



struct TestStruct9 {
    uint8 m_nOther1;
    uint8 m_nOther2;
    uint8 m_nOther3;
    uint8 m_nOther4;
    uint8 m_nOther5;
    uint8 m_nOther6;
    uint8 m_nOther7;
    uint8 m_nOther8;
    uint8 m_nOther9;
  }



TestStruct5[] internal m_testStruct5;
  TestStruct6[] internal m_testStruct6;
  TestStruct7[] internal m_testStruct7;
  TestStruct8[] internal m_testStruct8;
  TestStruct9[] internal m_testStruct9;



function GasTest5(address a_owner) external returns (uint256)
  {
    TestStruct5 memory item = TestStruct5({
      m_nOther1 : 0,
      m_nOther2 : 0,
      m_nOther3 : 0,
      m_nOther4 : 0,
      m_nOther5 : 0
    });
    uint256 nItemID = m_testStruct5.push(item) - 1;
  }



function GasTest6(address a_owner) external returns (uint256)
  {
    TestStruct6 memory item = TestStruct6({
      m_nOther1 : 0,
      m_nOther2 : 0,
      m_nOther3 : 0,
      m_nOther4 : 0,
      m_nOther5 : 0,
      m_nOther6 : 0
    });
    uint256 nItemID = m_testStruct6.push(item) - 1;
  }



function GasTest7(address a_owner) external returns (uint256)
  {
    TestStruct7 memory item = TestStruct7({
      m_nOther1 : 0,
      m_nOther2 : 0,
      m_nOther3 : 0,
      m_nOther4 : 0,
      m_nOther5 : 0,
      m_nOther6 : 0,
      m_nOther7 : 0
    });
    uint256 nItemID = m_testStruct7.push(item) - 1;
  }



function GasTest8(address a_owner) external returns (uint256)
  {
    TestStruct8 memory item = TestStruct8({
      m_nOther1 : 0,
      m_nOther2 : 0,
      m_nOther3 : 0,
      m_nOther4 : 0,
      m_nOther5 : 0,
      m_nOther6 : 0,
      m_nOther7 : 0,
      m_nOther8 : 0
    });
    uint256 nItemID = m_testStruct8.push(item) - 1;
  }



function GasTest9(address a_owner) external returns (uint256)
  {
    TestStruct9 memory item = TestStruct9({
      m_nOther1 : 0,
      m_nOther2 : 0,
      m_nOther3 : 0,
      m_nOther4 : 0,
      m_nOther5 : 0,
      m_nOther6 : 0,
      m_nOther7 : 0,
      m_nOther8 : 0,
      m_nOther9 : 0
    });
    uint256 nItemID = m_testStruct9.push(item) - 1;
  }
```

The Gas output for the following is:

```
GasTest5 gas: 49046
GasTest6 gas: 49098
GasTest7 gas: 49206
GasTest8 gas: 86443
GasTest9 gas: 91843
```

We can see that adding a 6th and 7th element to the struct adds trivial extra gas, but once you add an 8th item the gas cost almost doubles and a 9th item is 5k+ extra gas. Since all items are uint8s the total is well below a uint256.

What is causing this? I have a lot of data to track related to an ERC721 and was hoping to pack most of it into a single uint256 struct but this causes major problems.

Edit: Truffle Compiler settings

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.5.2",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
       settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 1000
        },
        //evmVersion: "constantinople"
      }
    }
```

Edit 2: It seems to have to do with pushing the item into an array or mapping. Without that gas doesnt explode with more struct items. I wonder if copying it into storage with more than 7 variables causes problems. No one seems to know the answer and I can't find any info anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested it, and the transaction cost for `GasTest9` is `48926 gas`. What version of Solidity are you using and what compiler?

Comment: Added compiler settings to the post

Comment: I tried changing to 0.5.8 and get the same behavior

Comment: Are you using a 4.# compiler?

Comment: I am using solidity 0.5.2

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried in truffle but tested in remix Javascriot VM  and  Koban network.

Solidity Compiler **version:0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang**

**Test results :**

**Ethereum Remix:  Javascriot VM :**

```
Gastest5 gas:  46317
GasTest6 gas:  46831
GasTest7 gas:  47389
GasTest8 gas:  48013
GasTest9 gas:  48616
```

**Kovan Network :**

First Call:

```
Gastest5 gas:  70317 
GasTest6 gas:  75631 
GasTest7 gas:  80989 
GasTest8 gas:  86413 
GasTest9 gas:  91816
```

**Second Call:**

```
Gastest5 gas:  55317  
GasTest6 gas:  60631
GasTest7 gas:  65989
GasTest8 gas:  71413  
GasTest9 gas:  76816
```

Comment: Hmm. Possibly truffle gas estimator is wrong?

Comment: @JohnSnow  I  will  test with  later  and update answer with truffle results.

Comment: I'm still checking daily. Hoping to get some confirmed answers on this. It greatly effects my design for my contract. If I can only have 7 items I have to do my own bit packing which is annoying but workable.

Comment: Anything new? Has anyone done struct gas optimization tests that are out there somewhere?